# Send proxy auth in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I write an extension to send proxy auth every time Chrome ask for proxy user/pwd, but it has a problem every time when I open a webpage that req http basic auth, it stops at 'Waiting for XXXX', XXXX is my extension name.

My code like:

```
var gPendingCallbacks = [];
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(handleAuthRequest,
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["asyncBlocking"]);

function processPendingCallbacks() {
  var callback = gPendingCallbacks.pop();
  callback({authCredentials: {username: 'user',
                              password: 'pass'}});
}

function handleAuthRequest(details, callback) {
  gPendingCallbacks.push(callback);
  if (details.isProxy === true ){
  processPendingCallbacks();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you point to where in the docs `authCredentials` is used as an object key?  I thought you had to supply a `Authorization` or `Proxy-Authorization` header with a base64-encoded value.

Comment: @apsillers http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html#type-BlockingResponse

Comment: if `details.isProxy` is false, the request will never call back and the browser process will hang.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
function handleAuthRequest(details, callback) {
    gPendingCallbacks.push(callback);
    if (details.isProxy === true ){
        processPendingCallbacks();
    }
}
```

to:

```
function handleAuthRequest(details, callback) {
    gPendingCallbacks.push(callback);
    processPendingCallbacks();
}
```